# Printing in JS page an array from React method in other file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React.
I have two files: biologia.js and fleekstorage-functions.js
In fleekstorage-functions.js there are Fleek Storage method that can list files from my bucket:

```
const ListFiles = async () => {
    const input = {
        apiKey,
        apiSecret,
        getOptions: [
            'bucket',
            'key',
            'hash',
            'publicUrl'
        ],
    };

    try {
        const result = await fleek.listFiles(input);
        return result
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error', e);
    }
}
```

And in biologia.js I have:

```
var articoli = ListFiles()
const Biologia = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <br/><br/>
            <h1 className="titolo">Articoli di Biologia:</h1>
            <p className="titolo">Qui si parlerà di biologia.</p>
            {articoli}
        </>
    );
}
```

As you look I wanted to print on a page the output of ListFiles, but console returned me this error:

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Could you please help me to print the array and single elements of it on biologia.js?

Comment: You are trying to render as a component something that is not a component. `articoli` does not seems to be a component.

Comment: So how can I print it as html?

Comment: Remove, or comment, the line `{articoli}`, and instead of that type in `console.log(articoli);` right before of the return block. Then watch what is printed in the browser's console.

Comment: It appears you may need to parse/transform your `result` to something that can be rendered. May be, initially, trying to replace `return result` with `return JSON.stringify(result);` would at least show some string/text.

Comment: It returns me a pending message because the method is async and have an await, but it doesn't return me the array (also if I have the return on the method).

`Promise { <state>: "pending" }
biologia.js:8`

Comment: Same result with `return JSON.stringify(result);`

Comment: You can use `useState` and update the state when you receive your list object and then use `.map()` on the state to render your list.

Comment: I tried to use useState: `const result = useState(await fleek.listFiles(input));`
and to map: `result.map((test) => (return test))`
but IDE make an error on "return test" telling me that I cant' use return.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem here seems to be that `ListFiles()` is an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). In other words, it will always return a Promise, meaning `var articoli = ListFiles()` will always store a Promise inside `articoli`.

As indicated by the error you're seeing, a Promise isn't a renderable element. You'll have to wait for the Promise to be resolved, then transform the results as desired into what you want to render. For example, set up your state with a [Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html):

```
const [articoli, setArticoli] = useState(null);
```

Then you can set the value after the Promise from `ListFiles()` has resolved:

```
ListFiles().then((list) => {
    // If the file list needs to be converted into JSX, do it here. E.g.:
    const mappedList = list.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <p key={index}>{item}</p>
        );
    });
    setArticoli(mappedList);
    
    // Otherwise, just set the value directly:
    setArticoli(list);
});
```

Comment: The page returns me "invalid hooks call". I putted all the modifies in biologia.js, is it right?

Comment: @Rekcah Does biologia.js contain a function component, or a class component? Hooks are only valid to call within a function component. There are various problems suggested by the error, so you'll need to assess whether your code has any of them.