# Invalid hook call for Fleek Storage with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Threaded from: [Printing in JS page an array from React method in other file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71083667/printing-in-js-page-an-array-from-react-method-in-other-file/71084664#71084664)

I modified biologia.js in this way:

```
const Biologia = () => {
    const [, setArticoli] = useState(null);
    ListFiles().then((list) => {
        // If the file list needs to be converted into JSX, do it here. E.g.:
        const mappedList = list.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <p key={index}>{item}</p>
            );
        });
        setArticoli(mappedList);

        // Otherwise, just set the value directly:
        setArticoli(list);
    });

    return (
        <>
            <br/><br/>
            <h1 className="titolo">Articoli di Biologia:</h1>
            <p className="titolo">Qui si parlerà di biologia.</p>
        </>
    );
}

export default Biologia;
```

but it returns me this error:

```
    error Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

        You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
        You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
        You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

I'm trying to fix it, but I don't know how to do it. Can you help me please?

Stack Snippet:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const ListFiles = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve([
                "one",
                "two",
                "three",
                "four",
            ]);
        }, 800);
    });
};

const Biologia = () => {
    const [, setArticoli] = useState(null);
    ListFiles().then((list) => {
        // If the file list needs to be converted into JSX, do it here. E.g.:
        const mappedList = list.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <p key={index}>{item}</p>
            );
        });
        setArticoli(mappedList);

        // Otherwise, just set the value directly:
        setArticoli(list);
    });

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <br/><br/>
            <h1 className="titolo">Articoli di Biologia:</h1>
            <p className="titolo">Qui si parlerà di biologia.</p>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

const Example = () => {
    return <Biologia />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi! I've copied your code into a runnable Stack Snippet and as you can see, it doesn't cause the error you describe. (It does have a problem, but not the problem you've described.) Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem by editing the Stack Snippet. (Note that, sadly, you have to use `<React.Fragment>` instead of `<>` because [Stack Snippets are out of date](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400732/please-fix-stack-snippets)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your code doesn't have the problem you've quoted, it does have a major problem: It endlessly re-requests the files from `ListFiles`. Remember that the body of a component function is called **every time** React renders your component, which it does after every state change (and often at other times).

To do one-time initial work on mounting, you us a `useEffect` hook with an empty dependency array, like this *(I've also modified the component to show the list it builds)* — see `***` comments:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const ListFiles = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve([
                "one",
                "two",
                "three",
                "four",
            ]);
        }, 800);
    });
};

const Biologia = () => {
    // *** Actually receive the state element
    const [articoli, setArticoli] = useState(null);

    // *** Use `useEffect` to do a one-time process on mount
    useEffect(() => {
        let unmounted = false;
        // *** If you can pass `ListFiles` a cancellation token of some kind
        // (like `AbortSignal`) use that instead of `unmounted`.
        ListFiles()
        .then((list) => {
            if (unmounted) {
                return;
            }
            // If the file list needs to be converted into JSX, do it here. E.g.:
            const mappedList = list.map((item, index) => {
                // *** Beware that using the `index` as key is often incorrect
                return (
                    <p key={index}>{item}</p>
                );
            });
            setArticoli(mappedList);

            // Otherwise, just set the value directly:
            // setArticoli(list);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            if (unmounted) {
                return;
            }
            // ...handle/report error...
        });
        // *** Return a cleanup callback so we don't do anything if unmounted
        // before the promise is settled
        return () => {
            unmounted = true;
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <br/><br/>
            <h1 className="titolo">Articoli di Biologia:</h1>
            <p className="titolo">Qui si parlerà di biologia.</p>
            {   // Actually include the articles
                articoli
            }
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

const Example = () => {
    return <Biologia />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```